# Using @@error and @@rowcount in stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

My stored procedure accepts `xml` data, the number of rows that can be generated from this `xml` data is unknown forehand.

In this I need to handle transactions when saving this `xml` data to a table. I cannot use `@@rowcount` to check whether the insert is successful because all rows in the `xml` are inserted at once. Therefore the only option I have is `@@error`. Assume the `xml` contains 10 rows of data, if one record failed to insert would `@@error` detect it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing the actual INSERTs, but in general the answer is yes. And if it's a single statement and it errors, there will be no rows inserted after rollback; otherwise it depends on your error handling code.

I'd recommend using TRY .. CATCH to handle errors instead of @@ERROR function.

There is a very good article by Erland Sommarskog about error handling in SQL Server you should read:

http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html#batchabort1

And a newer one as well:

http://sommarskog.se/error_handling_2005.html